# fread() not working as expected

Tags: c, struct, endianness, fread

I have an .obj file whose contents are as follows:

```
0000000 ca de 00 00 00 07 12 01 14 49 16 91 12 da 52 83
0000010 52 d2 52 da                                    
0000014
```

I would like to read its contents into a struct that points to an integer array called memory:

```
typedef struct {
   // ....Some code....

    // Machine memory - all of it
    unsigned short int memory[65536];
} MachineState;
```

However I'm having trouble with `fread()`. After declaring it in the following manner:

```
FILE *src_file = fopen(filename, "rb");
        //Read from binary file
        int byte = fread(theMachineState->memory, 1, sizeof(unsigned short), src_file);

        //Below are print statements for theMachineState->memory and byte..
```

I only ever see `cade` in `memory[]` (or `deca` depending on the endianness of machine). It fails to read the rest of the contents. What am I missing here? Calling `fread()` two times in a row populates `memory[]` with a single zero and in both cases, the number of bytes read is always 2.

Any help is sincerely appreciated!

Comment: What do you expect `sizeof(unsigned short)` to return?

Comment: Yes, unsigned short is two bytes so I see the error I made here.

Answer (score 2):

[`fread()` takes two parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) that establish how many bytes will be read. Since you are passing `size == 1` and `count == sizeof(unsigned short)`, you are asking `fread()` to read (probably) 2 objects of size 1 -- which is why you are seeing only `cade` in memory (assuming you called it twice, somehow).

Instead of doing that, ask for:

```
fread(theMachineState->memory, sizeof(unsigned short), 65536, src_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not "failing" to read the rest; you're telling it to read just one `unsigned short`.

```
fread(theMachineState->memory, 1, sizeof(unsigned short), src_file);
```

The second and third arguments are called `size` and `nmemb`, which are meant to be the size of each data item and the number of data items to read.  You're passing 1 (i.e. each item is 1 byte) and `sizeof(unsigned short)`, which probably equals 2.  So you're telling it to read two bytes.

You probably meant to do something like:

```
fread(theMachineState->memory, sizeof(unsigned short), 65536, src_file);
```

(which will return the number of `unsigned short` values read, i.e. 65536 if it fills the whole buffer), or:

```
fread(theMachineState->memory, 1, sizeof(theMachineState->memory), src_file);
```

(which will return the number of *bytes* read, i.e. probably 131072 if it fills the whole buffer).

Comment: Thank you. I made the first suggested edits and my output reads 10 bytes, but my array is still only being populated with "cade" which I'm confirming with a simply print statement. Why isn't the array being populated? I will eventually be writing this to a text file so I need confirmation that the array is being populated.

Comment: @J_code: "*confirming with a simply print statement.*" you want to make this another question.

Comment: @alk: And please also include a complete code example in the new question if possible; otherwise, it is hard to guess.

Comment: You haven't said what sort of print statement you're using, but the "cade" is followed by a null byte, which string-handling functions will interpret as the end of the string.  So if you're trying to print the whole array as a string, output will stop there.